# Where can I buy a one-shot manga called 'Prisoner' (written in Katakana)?

Tags: prisoner

I have been searching for a one-shot manga called *Prisoner* since years ago.

The story starts with a salaryman got back home at night and found out his house was really messy. Through the story, the writer leads the readers to believe that the man killed a girl that seemed to be his partner. In the last page, the panel shows a building with only one small window and the bars inside can be seen through it. The ending...

> It makes readers think that the man got in jail for killing the girl. Next, the bars turned out to be mop handles and other cleaning stuff. The plot twist: he is actually a clean freak and never killed the girl. The story is mind-blowing.

I downloaded the manga but can't find where it is sold anywhere. Where can I buy it?

Comment: You're trying to find a place to buy it, I assume? An actual physical copy?

Comment: @JNat I assume the OP failed to find the site from where they downloaded/read it (possibly taken down if unlicensed). That said, OP: this community doesn't support piracy, so we will only provide legal ways (if exists). Lastly, I assume you're looking for the English translated, not the original language (or Japanese)?

Answer (score 2):

The one-shot is titled ***プリズナー*** (*purizunaa*, *Prisoner*) by Masakazu Ishiguro.

[image: title page of "Prisoner"]

It was serialized in ***もっと！*** (*motto!*, *More!*) ***vol.7***, published in August 2014.

[image: cover image of "motto!" vol.7 magazine]

It can be bought on [Amazon Japan](https://www.amazon.co.jp/%E3%82%82%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A8-Vol-7-2014%E5%B9%B4-08%E6%9C%88%E5%8F%B7-%E9%9B%91%E8%AA%8C/dp/B00KLIH8SI).

---

*The magazine is on hiatus since the end of 2014 and there doesn't seem any licensed English translation of it.